# Internal Server Exception - Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

Internal Server Exception - Failed to convert from type [java.util.ArrayList<?>] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue] for value  nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.springboot.cassandrapoc.model.Attribute] to type [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.data.UdtValue]

Comment: Please provide your code where the exception is happening and also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further questions that you ask.

Comment: also add the schema for your table